# What are Abe and Aaron saying to each other just before Aaron intercepts the gunman at the party?

Tags: primer

In the scene in *Primer* in which Aaron stops the gunman at the party, the narrator mentions "last minute moral debate" as Abe and Aaron are shown talking to each other. Only the narrator's voice is on the soundtrack. At the end of the exchange, Aaron turns and heads toward the gunman.

This sequence takes place between 1:11:55 and 1:12:15.

Is there any clue about what they are saying to each other at this point? Perhaps something from the script or someone's effort to read their lips? (To clarify: My question is whether anyone knows what are the exact words being said.)

Comment: "Yo dawg, I know you like time travel so I put some time travel in your time travel"

Answer (score 1):

They are trying to engineer the situation such that Aaron saves the day at Rachel's party as happened in some previous (but likely not the original) timeline. However, as revealed during the basketball scene, they were part of the reason the guy showed up at the party in the first place. So why not stop him from showing up instead by just not inviting his cousin? They initially justify it in that he will go to jail and thus Rachel will be safe if he does show up with a shotgun.

However, it is shown that they have modified the timeline so much, and their declining health keeps them from emulating the basketball game and conversations properly that they are the ones that have to plant the shotgun for him to find to begin with because he no longer comes with his cousin. (It's not entirely clear what happened in the previous timeline, but when Aaron misses the shot the conversation goes off the rails and he has to explicitly ask for him to tell Rachel's ex where she will be rather than him organically showing up with his cousin)

The motivation becomes the purely selfish reason of wanting to appear as a hero so their moral standing becomes even more tenuous and hence the discussion and argument about the morality of what they are doing.